# DevExpress XtraGrid: Make column visible to user

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a grid with lots of columns (ca. 100). I've written a column selector context menu (which has each letter of the alphabet and then as subitems all the columns beginning with that letter).

When the user clicks in the context menu I want to make the column they have chosen visible to the user (preferably in the middle of the visible grid). I don't want to actually mess with the column order, I just want to make sure a column is visible to the user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the following approach:

1) set the column's Visible property to true.

2) if you want this column to be in the middle of the grid, set its VisibleIndex property to gridView.VisibleColumnsCount / 2;

3) call the GridView's MakeColumnVisible method to make this column visible to the end user.

Comment: MakeColumnVisible was the key. But VisibleColumns.Count returns the total columns in the grid, so does not automatically ensure that the column is the middle one visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GridColumn.VisibleIndex property to change the order in which columns are displayed.

VisibleIndex = -1 hides a column IIRC.